# JQuery Data Table reflecting single character

Tags: datatables

I have a fairly simple javascript array named arr with two strings pushed into it.

```
arr.push("first");
arr.push("second");
```

Data table code is:

```
j$("data_table").DataTable({data:arr,columns:[{"title":"Position"}]});
```

Why is only single character of two strings getting displayed in the table.

Comment: Because string is an array itself, and dataTables needs at least an array of arrays. Use `arr.push(["first"]);` etc instead. **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/961/**

Comment: Thanks, that worked!